# Combine multiple count matrices in R

Tags: r

I have 5 matrices with 3 common columns and more than 400K rows. Each column has chromosome, genomic position and read counts per position. However, each matrix has different number of rows.

```
> head(SM1Counts)
          Chromosome Position SM1x
27275 NW_017614756.1    17486 5425
3568     NC_013663.1     2626 4173
9087     NC_013663.1     5935 4153
9546     NC_013663.1     6223 3830
8094     NC_013663.1     5346 3491
27569 NW_017614756.1    17749 3388

> head(BM1Counts)
          Chromosome Position BM1x
8630     NC_013663.1     5935 3656
3414     NC_013663.1     2626 3449
7728     NC_013663.1     5346 3333
9093     NC_013663.1     6223 3163
3132     NC_013663.1     2445 2670
25920 NW_017614756.1    17486 2625
```

As you can see above, there are rows between the matrices that contain the same information but different counts.
I would like to create a new matrix where I will get all the similar chromosomes/positions between samples but the counts should be an extra column like this:

```
> exmatrix
      Chromosome Position BM1x SM1x
1 NW_017614255.1    18550  106  200
2 NW_017616165.1    18794   50   43
3 NW_017616275.1    18344   20   15
4 NW_017614354.1    18694   51   62
5 NW_017616171.1     6199   35   18
```

I have been trying to do this with various ways but I fail.

merge works only with two matrices if I am not wrong but I have 5.
Tried to do it step by step but it takes a lot of time and at the end I don't get what I want:

```
> head(BCounts)
        Chromosome.x Position.x BM1x   Chromosome.y Position.y BM3x
27054 NW_017614255.1      18550  106 NW_017614756.1      17486 4105
27337 NW_017616165.1      18794   50 NW_017614756.1      17749 4073
26830 NW_017616275.1      18344   20 NW_017614756.1      17297 3508
27223 NW_017614354.1      18694   51 NW_017614756.1      17628 3281
9064  NW_017616171.1       6199   35    NC_013663.1       5935 3139
3636  NW_017613961.1       2781    1    NC_013663.1       2626 3059
```

Comment: Have a look at `Reduce`. For example `Reduce(function(...) merge(...,by=c("Chromosome","Position")),list(SM1Counts,BM1Counts))` .

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
However I am reading about the "function (f)" and all the options and I am unable to understand what kind of function I need.
I also see some examples like function(x) or function(x,y) but what does this mean?

Comment: Actually what I really need to do with these matrices is:
merge them in a new matrix by Chromosome and Position and then the values that are not found in all of the matrices need to be set on zero.

Comment: Thats what the code does ;) Try `Reduce(function(...) merge(...,by=c("Chromosome","Position"),all=TRUE),list(SM1Counts,BM1C‌​ounts))` with `SM1Counts` and `BM1C‌​ounts`being your data frames. You can add the remaining data frames in the list.

Comment: Well, you can tell I am an R-newbe.
It is working as you wrote it down.
Thank you very much.